# Neural Network Toolbox in Matlab get different results each time even if the initial weights are all zeros

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

Why should be closed and reopened the MATLAB windows for again running the neural network in order to get the same result? What parameters are effectively in this process?

**EDIT (More details on my problem)**
If I don't close all windows of MATLAB and don't re-open them to run another net (such as run by another number of neurons), the obtained results is different from every time that I close and reopen the windows. For example: I run the ANN by 5 neurons in hidden layer and get the R(1)=0.97, then I close and reopen my m.file and run by 5 neurons and get R(2)=0.58.Now, if I don't close and don't reopen, I may get R(1)=0.99 and R(2)=0.7 (R is regression). What parameters is effective so that these answers be different?

my code is as follow:

```
clc
clear
for m=6:7

   % P is input matrix for training
   % T is output matrix 

   [Pn,minP,maxP,Tn,minT,maxT] = premnmx(P,T);

   net=newff(minmax(Pn),[m,1],{'logsig','purelin'},'trainlm');

   net.trainParam.show =100;
   net.trainParam.lr = 0.09;
   net.trainParam.epochs =1000;
   net.trainParam.goal = 1e-3; 

   [net,tr]=train(net,Pn,Tn);
   diff= sim(net,Pn);
   diff1 = postmnmx(diff,minT,maxT)

   %testing===================================================================
   [Pn,minP,maxP,Tn,minT,maxT] = premnmx(P,T);
   % Pt is input matrix data for testing 
   % Tt is output matrix data for testing

   Ptn = tramnmx(Pt,minP,maxP)
   diff= sim(net,Ptn);
   diff2 = postmnmx(diff,minT,maxT)

   msetr=mse(diff1-T)
   msets=mse(diff2-Tt)

   y=(1/n)*sum(diff2); % n is number of testing data
   R2=((sum((Tt-y).^2))-(sum((diff2-Tt).^2)))/(sum((Tt-y).^2))

   net.IW{1,1}=zeros(m,5);
   net.LW{2,1}=zeros(2,m);
   net.b{1,1}=zeros(m,1);
   net.b{2,1}=zeros(2,1);

end
```

when I run that, the answers for each number of neurons is different from time which I don't use a "for.. end" loop and run for each number of neurons by reopening the m-file and MATLAB windows.
However I give zero value to weights, didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what do you mean by Matlab windows, but you can control the pop-up of nntraintool GUI (`nntraintool('close')`) by putting

```
yournet.trainParam.showWindow = false;
yournet.trainParam.showCommandLine = false;
```

after your network `yournet`'s definition but before the training function.

**EDIT: my reply to the OP's EDIT**
I attached my training and test code based on yours, I tried to learn `y = x.^2`, and my training data is [1,3,5,7,9] for `x`, and [2,4,6,8] for test. Yet I should say I got different weights every time even if the initial weights are all zero. That means given the hidden layer nodes of 6 or 7, the back propagation won't achieve unique solution. Please see my revisions below:

```
clc
clear

for m=6:7

   % P is input matrix for training
   % T is output matrix 
   P=[1 3 5 7 9];
   T=P.^2;
   [Pn,minP,maxP,Tn,minT,maxT] = premnmx(P,T);
   clear net
   net.IW{1,1}=zeros(m,1);
   net.LW{2,1}=zeros(1,m);
   net.b{1,1}=zeros(m,1);
   net.b{2,1}=zeros(1,1);
   net=newff(minmax(Pn),[m,1],{'logsig','purelin'},'trainlm');

   net.trainParam.show =100;
   net.trainParam.lr = 0.09;
   net.trainParam.epochs =1000;
   net.trainParam.goal = 1e-3; 

   [net,tr]=train(net,Pn,Tn);
   diff= sim(net,Pn);
   diff1 = postmnmx(diff,minT,maxT)

   %testing===================================================================
   [Pn,minP,maxP,Tn,minT,maxT] = premnmx(P,T);
   % Pt is input matrix data for testing 
   % Tt is output matrix data for testing
   Pt=[2 4 6 8];
   Tt=Pt.^2;
   n=length(Pt);
   Ptn = tramnmx(Pt,minP,maxP)
   diff= sim(net,Ptn);
   diff2 = postmnmx(diff,minT,maxT)

   msetr=mse(diff1-T)
   msets=mse(diff2-Tt)

   y=(1/n)*sum(diff2); % n is number of testing data
   R2=((sum((Tt-y).^2))-(sum((diff2-Tt).^2)))/(sum((Tt-y).^2))


end
```

Actually if you add

```
aa=net.LW(2,1);
aa{1}
```

right before

```
[net,tr]=train(net,Pn,Tn);
```

you will find the weights are different every time you run it. Different Matlab Neural networks toolbox results is because of two reasons: **(1) random data division**, and **(2) random weight initialization**. Even if you zerolize the initial weight every time that you avoid (2), (1) still exists since `dividerand` randomizes the order of the input/target pairs.

One trick to compromise this is to record the first time's weight. In my case, I added:

```
   bb = [ -0.2013   -0.8314    0.4717    0.4266    0.1441   -0.6205];
   net.LW{2,1} = bb;
   bbb = [-16.7956 -16.8096 16.8002 16.8001 -16.8101 -16.8416]';
   net.IW{1}=bbb;
   bbbb=0.2039;
   bbbbb=[-16.8044 -10.0608 3.3530 -3.3563 -10.0588 -16.7584]';
   net.b{1}=bbbbb;
   net.b{2}=bbbb;
```

before `[net,tr]=train(net,Pn,Tn);`, then the result won't change. You may need to work on your own case by recording the `net.b`, `net.IW`, and `net.LW` values, and use them every time in your loop (`save` your `net` for the 1st trial run, and `load net` to get the value of `net.b`, `net.IW`, and `net.LW` in your loop run).

Yet I don't think this method make much sense. What I highly recommend you is to:

1. Initialize the rand weights.
2. Use an outer loop that specifies the number of hidden nodes,`m`
3. Use an inner loop that creates a net with a new set of random initial weights for each m; then trains, evaluates, and stores the `R2` in a 2-D matrix.
4. Search the stored results for the smallest net with an acceptable performance, record the `m`.
5. Run several times in a loop with the determined `m` values and only store the index or weights of the current best design.
6. Select the weights with best performance

Comment: If I don't close all windows of MATLAB and don't reopenning them to run another net (such as run by another number of neurons), the obtained results is different from every time that I close and reopen the windows. For example: I run the ANN by 5 neurons in hidden layer and get the R(1)=0.97, then I close and reopen my m.file and run by 5 neurons and get R(2)=0.58.Now, if I don't close and don't reopen, I may get R(1)=0.99 and R(2)=0.7 (R is regression).What parameters is effective so that these answers be different?

Comment: it is possible that you get different results. It's due to the weight initialization (every time you re-run the program the initial weights are different). Yet I don't think it has something to do with close-open windows.

Comment: I give zero value to every weights and layer weights and biases (I done this work as I use a "for..end" loop (for example: for m=0:10 so that m is the number of neurons in hidden layer) and give zero value to every weights at before I write "end". But answers were different. may should write ANN without matlab tools! how can done it?

Comment: your hidden layers are different each time? so definitely the R will not be the same.  I would suggest you paste your code on your original post by clicking 'edit', so people can find out more details.

Comment: yes, my number of neurons in each layer is different each time. please see my code which added in my original post

Comment: see my update in answer. It's possible to get different learning results.

Comment: yes, I am agree with you, the weights are different each time even though they be zero at start. If I don't use from "for.. end" and reopen the windows for re_run another number of neuron, my answers will be same. but, I will use "for.. and" loop. what do I do for solve my problem? What is your idea?

Comment: I got different result even if i removed the for loop and use m=6; instead.

Comment: If you remove the for loop, run for m=6 and close the all windows and reopen your m-file and re-run, the answers will be same.

Comment: I didn't can understand your idea,clearly. Do I add  " net.IW{1,1}=rand(m,5);
    net.LW{2,1}=rand(2,m);
    net.b{1,1}=rand(m,1);
    net.b{2,1}=rand(2,1); " before train ? How can I add inner loop in my program? Can I send my m.file to your email for reviewing it?If you can see it and add your idea at that,it will be a big help to me.Thanks and with regard.

Comment: @skbn run your original program 1 time for m =6, without any loop, after finished, save net net   After that start to run the program in the loop, but change your code inside the loop to :[Pn,minP,maxP,Tn,minT,maxT] = premnmx(P,T); load net; [net,tr]=train(net,Pn,Tn);

Comment: don't reinitialize net anymore

Comment: Excuse me, How can I save net for m=6 ?

Comment: save net net    put this line at the end of your function

Comment: sorry, should I done follow?:" for m=6:7,..load net,train,..,save net net,end " OK? Is that right? I get the same answer for each m value!

Comment: don't save net again when you start to run the program in a loop

Comment: I'm confused. May be that say me where put save net net in "for m=6:10 ... end".Assume I start running, I write m=6:10 then, write program,then write end . now, where do put save net net?  really excuse me.

Comment: for m=6:10...end save net net    Then re-run the program for m=6:10...end...but this time don't save net again!

Comment: remember to load net when you run for m=6:10 for 2nd time, but don't load in the 1st run

Comment: I exactly done how you say: run " for..and,save net net",then I delete save net net and add load net and run "for..load net...end". But didn't solve my problem, I get the same answer for each m value.